# Setting width of textview in a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am using a header for a Listview. ListView header has three columns. Say a,b,c. I am using two LinearLayouts to design ListView header as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="40dip"  
 android:padding="0dip">  
 <LinearLayout  
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:background="#1e90ff"  
    android:layout_width="0dip"  
    android:layout_weight="1"  
    android:padding="5dip"  
    android:layout_height="40dip">  
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/a"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:text="@string/a"  
    />  
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:id="@+id/b"  
        android:singleLine="true"  
        android:text="@string/b"  
    />  
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:id="@+id/c"  
        android:singleLine="true"  
        android:text="@string/c"  
    />  
 </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to fix the width of columns a, b, c respectively. How to set width of these columns ? Again, is it a good practise to use LinearLayout for this ? Please Advise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change the layout_width of your textviews to a fixed width use:

```
 android:layout_width="40dip"
```

Or of you want them to take up percentages of the screen change the layout_weight

```
 android:layout_weight="2"
```

In android the weight of all elements within another one (such as your linear layout here) will be added together and then using the weight of each view to define how much space it takes. I.E. if you had the weights as 2,3,5 for a,b,c respectively, then a would be 20% wide, b 30% wide and c 50% wide.

If you want columns, you should consider using a table layout ([tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html))

Comment: THANKS A LOT for this simple and direct explanation. I'm new to layouts and this saved me a LOT of time.

Answer (score 4):

you can also set the width in percentage as follow

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#1e90ff" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:padding="5dip" 
    android:layout_height="40dip">

    <!--
      android:layout_weight="0.5"  <= it will set the 50 % width of screen
    -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/a" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:layout_weight="0.5"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:text="@string/a"  
    />  
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:layout_weight="0.5"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  
        android:id="@+id/b"  
        android:singleLine="true"  
        android:text="@string/b"  
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: An important thing to note is that it doesn't really matter what specific numbers you set the layout_weight-attribute to, it's the ratios that are important. For example, your XML would perform exactly the same if the 0.5 was swapped out for 1.0 or 5.0, just as long as you swapped it everywhere. Though your decimals are probably helpful, as you can easily count and see if they add up to 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setWidth()` method of `TextView` to set the size dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this within a layout that is used in a ListView, only setting the width dynamically in code works.  I actually have three TextViews in my list, but I'm only showing two here, for brevity.  Here is XML from the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sl_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sl_score"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code from within the Adapter for the ListView:

```
public View getView(int position, View cvtView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    int width = parent.getWidth();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scorelayout, parent, false);
    String str = values.get(position);
    String[] vals = str.split("\t");

    TextView tvName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.sl_name);
    tvName.setWidth((int)(width *.30));
    tvName.setText(vals[2]);

    TextView tvScore = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.sl_score);
    int stemp = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
    tvScore.setWidth((int)(width * .15));
    tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(stemp));
}
```